# How do I select objects when the ID is a small part of another column?

Tags: mysql, database

I have two tables, where the IDs found in one table (Table A) can be found in a column of the other table (Table B).  The column in Table B that contains the IDs from Table A also contains other information - more IDs from Table A as well as some unrelated data.  I cannot devise a query that will select the IDs from Table A that appear in Table B.  Example:

```
  Table A
| ID  | Name |
| mk5 | Peter|
| j9B | Paul |
| hop | Mary |

  Table B
| Type |                    Settings                    |
|  1   |      x=lmn,y=12a,z=ijg, one_thing=another      |
|  2   |     x=qza,y=j9B,z=hop, randomtext=and_more     |
|  3   | x=hop,y=toe,z=thu, somethingelse=somethingelse |
```

I thought a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE ID IN (SELECT Settings FROM TableB);
```

would identify IDs from Table A that were in the Settings column of TableB, but I get 0 rows returned.  Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: While I appreciate the criticism of my example database, the design of it is outside of my control.  Obviously it would be easy to find what I'm looking for if the values were in single columns, that is why I'm asking for help.
It also would be very difficult to have the values found in "Settings" split into multiple columns.  You would need several dozen columns to support the handful of entries that have a ton of settings.

Comment: @LelioFaieta who among us has been so lucky to have worked in a perfect codebase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the id of TableA appears after `=` and right before a `,` (unless it is at the end) in the `Settings` column then you can join the tables and use `LIKE` operator in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT a.*, b.* 
FROM TableA a INNER JOIN TableB b
ON concat(b.settings, ',') LIKE concat('%=', a.id, ',%')
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW - Forpas's answer helped me, but this query ended up solving it for me:

```
SELECT a.ID FROM a, b WHERE INSTR(b.Settings, CONCAT('=', a.ID)) != 0 
AND INSTR(b.Settings, concat(a.ID, ',')) != 0;

SELECT ID FROM a WHERE ID NOT IN (select a.ID from a, b where 
INSTR(b.Settings, CONCAT('=', a.ID)) != 0 AND INSTR(b.Settings, concat(a.ID, ',')) != 0);
```

First query selects IDs in **table a** that appear in **table b**, second query selects IDs in **table a** that do not appear in **table b**.

The INSTR(x,y) MySQL function checks for String y in String x, returning a character position if found.  If not, returns 0.